# Not being able to verify apps

Tags: iphone, applications, ios, verify

I have an iPhone SE, running iOS 12. As part of a programming course I do, we made some apps. 4 in total.

Whenever I try to open one of these apps I get this message:

[image: the message]

However when I go to settings and verify it tries to verify it as shown here:

[image: trying to verify it]

But then it goes back to say not verified. How can I fix this?

EDIT: I am connected to WIFI and it works

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you please check if your iPhone has an active Internet connection?

Comment: @NimeshNeema I'm not that new :) Yes it does have a connection as demonstrated by the photos

Comment: The pictures don't show an Internet connection just connection to WiFi can you access anything via safari does the Internet router provide a proxy that you need to set up?

Comment: @Mark No it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have apps installed as "enterprise apps" - i.e. it is not apps installed via the App Store, via TestFlight or directly from Xcode as a developer. Enterprise app installation is supposed to be used only by enterprises installing their own custom apps on their own devices - it is not intended for public distribution.

In order to verify these apps, you'll need to have a working internet connection, and especially you must have unhindered access to https://ppq.apple.com [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204460)

However, it is not enough to have a working internet connection. The enterprise distribution account with Apple that was used to sign these apps must still be valid (i.e. subscription paid) - and the enterprise must not have revoked these specific apps.